# javascript/jquery variable not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

the script has 5 panels 3 of which are selectable and trigger the onclick event below.

it works fine and even alerts the value of "selectedID"

but when i try to change the values on the inputs and trigger the on click, keyup it gives me the error "selectedID not defined"

**Here is my JS**

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

///////////
     $("div.door").click(function () {

         resetall();
          $("div.door").removeClass("panelselected");
          $(this).toggleClass("panelselected");
          var selectedID = $(this).attr("id"); 
              alert(selectedID);


          $("#customisedoor").fadeIn("slow");
          $("#"+selectedID).animate({
                height: 118-Number($("#doorheight").val())*2+"px"

           }, 200 );
           var height = 118-Number($("#doorheight").val())*2;
           var topmargin = Number($("#doorheight").val())*2;
          $("#"+selectedID).css("margin-top", topmargin+"px");
          ////////////////////////////IF PANEL 2
          if(selectedID === 'panel2'){
$("#panel1").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button right appended"/>');
$("#panel3").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button left appended"/>');
          }
          ///////////////////////IF PANEL 3
          if(selectedID === 'panel3'){
$("#panel2").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button right appended"/>');  
$("#panel4").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button left appended"/>'); 
          }
          /////////////////////////
          ///////////////////////IF PANEL 3
          if(selectedID === 'panel4'){
$("#panel3").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button right appended"/>');  
$("#panel5").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button left appended"/>'); 
          }
          /////////////////////////
    });

    $("#doorwidth").keyup(function (){

           $("#"+selectedID).animate({
                width: $("#doorwidth").val()*2+"px"
              }, 200 );
$("#totalwidth").val(
    parseInt(300) + parseInt($("#doorwidth").val())
    );

});
    $("#doorwidth").click(function (){

           $("#"+selectedID).animate({
                width: $("#doorwidth").val()*2+"px"
              }, 200 );
$("#totalwidth").val(
    parseInt(300) + parseInt($("#doorwidth").val())
    );

});
    function calculateheight(){
         $("#"+selectedID).animate({
                height: 118-$("#doorheight").val()*2+"px"

              }, 200 );
              height = 118-$("#doorheight").val()*2;
              topmargin = $("#doorheight").val()*2;
        $("#"+selectedID).css("margin-top", topmargin+"px")
    }

        $("#doorheight").keyup(function (){
          calculateheight();
          });

        $("#doorheight").click(function (){
          calculateheight();

    });

    function resetall(){
        $(".appended").remove();
        $(".door").css({'width':'150','height':'118','margin':'0px'});
        $(".door").removeClass("panelselected");
        $("#doorheight").val(30);
        $("#doorwidth").val(75);
        $("#totalwidth").val(300+$("#doorwidth").val());

    }

    $("#reset").click(function () {
        //alert("removed");
        resetall();
    });
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    });
```

**Full source FROM Firefox**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!-- JS -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/validator/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/ui/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>



<!-- STYLES -->

<style>
<!-- LAYOUT -->


<!-- SKIRTS -->
.panelContainer{
height:128px;
width:900px;
float:left; 
}

.endpanel{
width:150px;
float:left;
height:118px;
background:#BFDDF2; 
border:1px solid #7DB8DB;
}
.panel{
width:150px;
bottom:0;
float:left;
height:118px;
background:#BFDDF2; 
border:1px solid #7DB8DB;
}

.mid{
    border-left:0px;
    }

.door:hover{
width:150px;
float:left;
height:118px;
background:#ECF5FB; 
border:1px solid #fff;
}

.panelselected{
width:150px;
float:left;
height:118px;
background:#ECF5FB; 
border:1px solid #fff;
}
.container{
    min-width:150px;
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    margin-top:3px;
    height:7px; 
    }

.button{
    width:7px; height:7px;
    margin:3px;

    }
.left{float:left;}
.right{float:right;}






</style>
</head>

<body>
<div style="width:780px; height:80px;float:left;">
    <h3>Please select a panel and customise the width and height to fit under your door step / doorway</h3>       

     <ul>
        <li>Total Draught Skirt Width: <input type="text" disabled id="totalwidth" value="375"/>(CMS)   </li>
     </ul>
</div>
<!-- CUSTOMISE DOOR -->



<div style="margin-top:20px; min-width:780px; height:80px;float:left;position:relative;">
        <div class="endpanel" id="panel1">
            <img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button left"/>
        </div>
        <div id="panel2" class="panel mid door">

        </div>
        <div id="panel3" class="panel mid door"></div>
        <div id="panel4" class="panel mid door"></div>
        <div class="endpanel mid" id="panel5">

            <img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button right"/>
        </div>
</div>

   <div id="customisedoor" style="clear:both; margin-top:50px;width:400px; height:80px;float:left; display:none;">


        <strong>Customise Your Door Panel</strong>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Width</td>

            <td>
                <input type="number" name="width" id="doorwidth" value="75"/>(CMS)
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Height From Top of Skirt: </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" name="height" id="doorheight" value="30"/>(CMS)
            </td>

       </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset"/></td>
    </tr>
        </table>


    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

///////////
     $("div.door").click(function () {
         resetall();
          $("div.door").removeClass("panelselected");
          $(this).toggleClass("panelselected");
          var selectedID = $(this).attr("id");


          $("#customisedoor").fadeIn("slow");
          $("#"+selectedID).animate({
                height: 118-Number($("#doorheight").val())*2+"px"

           }, 200 );
           var height = 118-Number($("#doorheight").val())*2;
           var topmargin = Number($("#doorheight").val())*2;
          $("#"+selectedID).css("margin-top", topmargin+"px");
          ////////////////////////////IF PANEL 2
          if(selectedID === 'panel2'){
$("#panel1").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button right appended"/>');
$("#panel3").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button left appended"/>');
          }
          ///////////////////////IF PANEL 3
          if(selectedID === 'panel3'){
$("#panel2").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button right appended"/>');  
$("#panel4").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button left appended"/>'); 
          }
          /////////////////////////
          ///////////////////////IF PANEL 3
          if(selectedID === 'panel4'){
$("#panel3").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button right appended"/>');  
$("#panel5").append('<img src="images/draught-skirts/button.png" class="button left appended"/>'); 
          }
          /////////////////////////
    });

    $("#doorwidth").keyup(function (){
                  alert("IDis"+selectedID);
           $("#"+selectedID).animate({
                width: $("#doorwidth").val()*2+"px"
              }, 200 );
$("#totalwidth").val(
    parseInt(300) + parseInt($("#doorwidth").val())
    );

});
    $("#doorwidth").click(function (){
        alert("IDis"+selectedID);
           $("#"+selectedID).animate({
                width: $("#doorwidth").val()*2+"px"
              }, 200 );
$("#totalwidth").val(
    parseInt(300) + parseInt($("#doorwidth").val())
    );

});
    function calculateheight(){
         $("#"+selectedID).animate({
                height: 118-$("#doorheight").val()*2+"px"

              }, 200 );
              height = 118-$("#doorheight").val()*2;
              topmargin = $("#doorheight").val()*2;
        $("#"+selectedID).css("margin-top", topmargin+"px")
    }

        $("#doorheight").keyup(function (){
          calculateheight();
          });

        $("#doorheight").click(function (){
          calculateheight();

    });

    function resetall(){
        $(".appended").remove();
        $(".door").css({'width':'150','height':'118','margin':'0px'});
        $(".door").removeClass("panelselected");
        $("#doorheight").val(30);
        $("#doorwidth").val(75);
        $("#totalwidth").val(300+$("#doorwidth").val());

    }

    $("#reset").click(function () {
        //alert("removed");
        resetall();
    });
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Jon Skeet wrote an interesting article you should take a look at: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/incomplete.html. Often in the process of reducing your problem to its core, you will figure out the bug yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

selectedID is out of scope - It's defined inside the click(...) function like below...

```
$("div.door").click(function () {
  ... 
  var selectedID = $(this).attr("id"); 
  ...
});
```

Which means selectedID only exists inside onClick anonymous function. It's not available in the keyup(...) function.

```
$("#doorwidth").keyup(function (){
  ...
  // selectedID is not available here, since it was declared inside click(...)
);
```

You'll want to something like this...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Define selectedID in an outer scope so it's available to all functions inside the closure.
  var selectedID;
  $("div.door").click(function () {
    ...
    // Instead of declaring selectedID inside this function, use selectedID from the outer scope.
    selectedID = $(this).attr("id"); 
    ...
  });

  $("#doorwidth").keyup(function (){
    // NULL check for selected ID
    if (selectedID) {
      $("#"+selectedID).animate({
        width: $("#doorwidth").val()*2+"px"
      }, 200 );
      $("#totalwidth").val(parseInt(300) + parseInt($("#doorwidth").val());
    }
  );

  ...
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You might try moving your var declaration outside of your jQuery click handler:

```
var selectedID = "";
```

And changing:

```
var selectedID = $(this).attr("id");
```

to:

```
selectedID = $(this).attr("id");
```

Comment: This solution will work because removing the var keyword means that the selectedID variable will be scoped globally. DashK's solution just increases the scope enough to be accessible.